# Reset Postgres' table sequence

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I have a table in my application `dockets` for which I want to reset the sequence/pk

I read that `sqlsequencereset` is used to do so but how do I do that for a single table and not the whole application

I tried:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset dockets
```

and it produced the following:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"dockets_materialrequestflow"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "dockets_materialrequestflow";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"dockets_materialrequest_flows"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "dockets_materialrequest_flows";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"dockets_materialrequest"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "dockets_materialrequest";
COMMIT;
```

How to proceed with only making changes in this particular table ?

Comment: Remove the lines that are not for the table you want before running the SQL?

Comment: Why do you want to reset the sequence? Sequences typically operate on primary keys and these tend not to have any inherent meaning (if so, you wouldn't be using a sequence in the first place). the value of the sequence should therefore be immaterial.

Comment: @Patrick There is a use case to do so in data migration from one application to another